# How can I connect to multiple Rabbitmq nodes with Spring Rabbitmq?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, amazon-elb

I am writing a service with Spring and I am using Spring AMQP in order to connect to Rabbitmq.

I have two rabbitmq clusters, one is only for publishing messages(the messages are sent to the other cluster via the federation plugin) and the other cluster is for declaring queues that end users will consume from.

The nodes sit behind aws lb, each cluster has a lb.

I am using CachingConnectionFactory and RabbitTemplate,RabbitAdmin in my code and I want to have connections to all the nodes so I can use them.
For the cluster that will contain the queues I added to the config the queue-master-locator=random so new queues will be declared in all the nodes in the cluster even if my service does not have a connection to them.

With the cluster that publishes messages I have more of a problem because I need a direct connection in my service to each of the nodes so I will be able to separate the load between the nodes.

So my problem is, how do I create connections in my service to all the nodes in the cluster so they will all be used for declaring queues and sending messages?

Now, after I will have some sort of solution to this issue, the next issue will be what happens when a new node is added to the cluster? How can I create a connection to it and start using it as well?

I am using Rabbitmq - 3.7.9, Spring - 2.0.5, Spring AMQP - 2.0.5

Thanks alot!

Comment: https://github.com/freenowtech/spring-multirabbit for anyone else hitting the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no mechanism to do anything like that.

By default, Spring AMQP opens only one connection (optionally two, one for publishing, one for consuming).

Even when using `CacheMode.CONNECTION`, you'll get a new connection for each consumer (and connections will be created and cached on demand for producers), you won't get any control as to which node it connects to; that's a function of the LB.

The framework does provide the `LocalizedQueueConnectionFactory` which will try to consume from the node that hosts a queue, but it won't work with a load balancer in place.

In general, however, such optimization is rarely needed.

Are you trying to solve an actual problem you are experiencing now, or something that you perceive that might be a problem?

It is generally best not to perform premature optimization.

Comment: Hey Gary, Thanks for the quick response :) Yes, I am trying to make some optimizations in my environment. But, even if I wanted to just set a single cluster with multiple nodes behind a LB that will serve both clients that are connecting to queues and my service that publishes messages, I would face the same problem which is that my service is not using all the node in order to publish messages. I want to make maximum use of each node I have in the cluster. The way I see it I want the nodes to separate between them the queues and that al of them will receive publish requests

Comment: There is nothing in the framework to help with that; you would have to define multiple connection factories and `RabbitTemplate`s, or create some kind of custom connection factory that hands-out connections round-robin fashion.